Neo4j "Cannot read field "next" because "e.currentToken" is null" persistent error
I recently received an assignement to learn how to use Neo4j. my first task was to open a CSV from loacal. Here's the command i typed:
load csv from 'file:///C:\Users\TBR\Documents\us-counties.csv' as row
merge (c:County{date:row[1], county: row[2], state: row[3], fips: row[4],})
set c.cases=toInteger(row[5]),c.deaths= toInteger(row[6])

However, it returned me the following error:
Cannot read field "next" because "e.currentToken" is null

I have difficulties finding anything online about this error. Does anyone happen to know why it popped up?
Here's the csv file structure:
Csv File structure

You cannot load from arbitrary local paths, as documented here.
The paths are relative to Neo4j installation folder.
Make sure to update the server configuration with dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls and server.directories.import.
